# no FPS in stream after publishNotify

Tags: apache-flex, video-streaming, live-streaming

I'm having difficulties in displaying live user stream.

when I'm attaching stream into Video object everything works great. but when user streams stop publishing and then publish again (for example after "hanging up" camera) i see that stream uses bandwidth but i don't get any fps.

After receiving "NetStream.Play.PublishNotify" I'm doing ns.play on stream.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: I didn't understand sense of calling ns.play after "NetStream.Play.PublishNotify". As for me NetStream.play should be called only once and doesn't matter if publish happens or not. It just listen for channel name.

Comment: for me too, but if I don't do it, i didn't recive any data from stream. i've fix it by deleting stream object on unpublish notify and creating new, but it's the ugliest solution i'v seen in this crap code i've to work with.